# Combining multiple columns into one

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataset as follows:

```
`      GN      Datum                      Land AG..GKV. MTCR..GKV. NSGI..GKV. NSGII..GKV. WA..GKV. ML..GKV.   Wert
8  11693 2012-01-05                     Kenia                                              5A001f          159700
9  11710 2012-01-05                    Indien 1C350.43                                                      18752
10 11749 2012-01-05 Taiwan, Provinz von China  2B350g2                                                      24000
11 11750 2012-01-05                    Indien                                    2B201a1  2B001b2          370296
12 11751 2012-01-05                   Serbien                                     2B201a                     7200
13 11752 2012-01-05                    Indien                                                           4c   6037
14 11753 2012-01-05                  Rumänien                                              2B001d            7830
15 11755 2012-01-06                     China                                    2B201a1                   215987
16 11756 2012-01-06                     China                                    2B201a1                   234736
17 11757 2012-01-06                 Brasilien                                      2B231                    69900
18 11758 2012-01-06                 Brasilien                                      2B231                   139800
19 11788 2012-01-07                 Kongo                                                                  139800
```

`GN` i a unique ID. As you can see, for each row, the variables `AG..GKV.` until `ML..GKV` hold one value at most, expect in the case where `GN == 11750`.

I would like to combine these variables into one, but still know what the original variable name was, like so:

```
`      GN      Datum                      Land variable value    Wert
8  11693 2012-01-05                     Kenia  WA..GKV. 5A001f   159700    
9  11710 2012-01-05                    Indien  AG..GKV. 1C350.43 18752
...
```

In the case where there are two values per row as in `GN == 11750`, it should look like this:

```
`      GN      Datum       Land   variable                value           Wert
11  11750 2012-01-05     Indien  NSGII..GKV.\nWA..GKV.    2B201a1\n2B201a 370296
```

i.e., the "double" variable and value should be separated by a new line delimiter.

**UPDATE**: *There is also a special case: When there is no value at all for one row*. I want to preserve these (see GN == 19 above and below). `variable` and `value` should just be empty in this case.

```
`      GN      Datum       Land   variable                value           Wert
19  11788 2012-01-07      Kongo                                           370296
```

I have no clue how to achieve this and have already tried the `reshape` package, but probably am too much of a R noob.

Here's a `dput` (not the same cases as above, but with all three kinds of outcomes):

```
    structure(list(GN = c(11789L, 11790L, 11791L, 11793L, 11794L, 
11795L, 11796L), Datum = structure(c(15355, 15355, 15355, 15355, 
15355, 15356, 15356), class = "Date"), Land = c("China", "Israel", 
"Pakistan", "Iran, Islamische Republik", "Hong Kong", "Südafrika", 
"Lettland"), AG..GKV. = c("2B350d4", "", "", "", "", "", ""), 
    MTCR..GKV. = c("", "", "", "", "", "", ""), NSGI..GKV. = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", "", ""), NSGII..GKV. = c("", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "2B201a1"), WA..GKV. = c("", "7A002a+b", "", "", 
    "3A001a2c", "6A003b4", "2B001b2"), ML..GKV. = c("", "", "", 
    "", "", "", ""), Wert = c(63720, 25672, 1608000, 10738, 202500, 
    13500, 374873)), .Names = c("GN", "Datum", "Land", "AG..GKV.", 
"MTCR..GKV.", "NSGI..GKV.", "NSGII..GKV.", "WA..GKV.", "ML..GKV.", 
"Wert"), row.names = 49:55, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option with tidyr and dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% gather(Variable, Value, AG..GKV.:ML..GKV.) %>% 
    filter(Value != "") %>% group_by(GN, Datum, Land) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(paste(unique(.), collapse = "\n")))

#Source: local data frame [11 x 6]
#Groups: GN, Datum
#
#      GN      Datum                      Land   Wert              Variable            Value
#1  11693 2012-01-05                     Kenia 159700              WA..GKV.           5A001f
#2  11710 2012-01-05                    Indien  18752              AG..GKV.         1C350.43
#3  11749 2012-01-05 Taiwan, Provinz von China  24000              AG..GKV.          2B350g2
#4  11750 2012-01-05                    Indien 370296 NSGII..GKV.\nWA..GKV. 2B201a1\n2B001b2
#5  11751 2012-01-05                   Serbien   7200           NSGII..GKV.           2B201a
#6  11752 2012-01-05                    Indien   6037              ML..GKV.               4c
#7  11753 2012-01-05                  Rumänien   7830              WA..GKV.           2B001d
#8  11755 2012-01-06                     China 215987           NSGII..GKV.          2B201a1
#9  11756 2012-01-06                     China 234736           NSGII..GKV.          2B201a1
#10 11757 2012-01-06                 Brasilien  69900           NSGII..GKV.            2B231
#11 11758 2012-01-06                 Brasilien 139800           NSGII..GKV.            2B231
```

Note that this will only create several entries separated by "\n" if there they are *unique*, which I assumed is what you want to do.

#### Edit after OP comment:

For your special case, try the following code:

```
DF %>% gather(Variable, Value, AG..GKV.:ML..GKV.) %>% 
    group_by(GN, Datum, Land) %>% filter(if(all(Value == "")) row_number() == 1 else Value != "") %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(paste(unique(.), collapse = "\n")))
```

Explanation:

- `gather` reshapes the data from wide to long format (using the columns AG..GKV. until ML..GKV.)
- Then we group the data by GN, Datum and Land
- The filter condition is: if all Value entries are empty strings, check if the row number is 1 (that means, return only the first row of such groups) else (if at least one or more Value entries are *not* empty strings) return only those rows which are not empty
- Then, on each of the columns  - except the grouping columns - summarise all unique values per group into a single string, separated by `\n`

Comment: Thanks. Does tidyr depend on dplyr? Or what library is responsible for what part of the code?

Comment: In my answer, `gather` is from `tidyr` and the rest is from `dplyr`. You don't have to use them together, but they are sort of made to work well together (by Hadley Wickham)

Comment: Alright. Your solution gives me `Error in filter(., Value != "") : object 'Value' not found` upon execution. Why is that?

Comment: Never mind, I did not explicitly load `dplyr`, I thought that would have been loaded with `tidyr` anyway. Now it works.

Comment: I've added a special case that I forgot about first, please see my updated question, maybe you can solve this too with `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The problem is that `filter(Value != "")` makes no distinction between such cases and "normal" ones.

Comment: I think the key lies in looking for such entries where *all* variables are empty, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I get exactly the same amount of rows.. Using only `filter(all(Value == ""))` gives 0 results.

Comment: You should update your question then with a new dput of the refined data.

Comment: @wnstnsmth, did you copy and paste the whole code from my answer? note that the `filter` statement is now _after_ the group_by.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to add a new `dput`. There you go (with other rows, but all three possible cases). A big sorry, I didn't copy paste but only adjusted the filter, now it works. Could you maybe elaborate a bit on your solution - I still don't fully understand what's happening (and will certainly dig into `dplyr` as soon as I have more time).

Answer (score 2):

You can try (df being your data.frame) :

variable name :

```
df$variable<-apply(df[,4:9],1,function(x){paste(colnames(df[,4:9])[which(x!="")],collapse="\n")})
```

value :

```
df$value<-apply(df[,4:9],1,function(x){paste(x[which(x!="")],collapse="\n")})
```

Finally, delete the original columns and reorganize :

```
df<-df[,c(1:3,11:12,10)]
```

Output :

```
> df
      GN      Datum                      Land              variable            value   Wert
8  11693 2012-01-05                     Kenia              WA..GKV.           5A001f 159700
9  11710 2012-01-05                    Indien              AG..GKV.         1C350.43  18752
10 11749 2012-01-05 Taiwan, Provinz von China              AG..GKV.          2B350g2  24000
11 11750 2012-01-05                    Indien NSGII..GKV.\nWA..GKV. 2B201a1\n2B001b2 370296
12 11751 2012-01-05                   Serbien           NSGII..GKV.           2B201a   7200
13 11752 2012-01-05                    Indien              ML..GKV.               4c   6037
14 11753 2012-01-05                  Rumänien              WA..GKV.           2B001d   7830
15 11755 2012-01-06                     China           NSGII..GKV.          2B201a1 215987
16 11756 2012-01-06                     China           NSGII..GKV.          2B201a1 234736
17 11757 2012-01-06                 Brasilien           NSGII..GKV.            2B231  69900
18 11758 2012-01-06                 Brasilien           NSGII..GKV.            2B231 139800
```