# Gather multiple date/value columns using tidyr

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I have a data set containing (amongst others) multiple columns with dates and corresponding values (repeated measurements). Is there a way to turn this into a long data set containing (the others and) only two columns - one for *dates* and one for *values* - using `tidyr`?

The following code produces an example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
   id = 1:10,
   age = sample(100, 10),
   date1 = as.Date('2015-09-22') - sample(100, 10),
   value1 = sample(100, 10),
   date2 = as.Date('2015-09-22') - sample(100, 10),
   value2 = sample(100, 10),
   date3 = as.Date('2015-09-22') - sample(100, 10),
   value3 = sample(100, 10))
```

The input table could (chance of `1` in `1.8x10^138`) look like this:

```
   id age      date1 value1      date2 value2      date3 value3
1   1  32 2015-08-01     37 2015-07-15     38 2015-09-09     81
2   2  33 2015-07-22     16 2015-06-26      1 2015-09-12     58
...
10 10  64 2015-07-23     78 2015-08-25     70 2015-08-05     90
```

What I finally want is this:

```
   id age       date  value
1   1  32 2015-08-01     37
2   1  32 2015-07-15     38
3   1  32 2015-09-09     81
4   2  33 2015-07-22     16
5   2  33 2015-06-26      1
...
30 10  64 2015-08-05     90
```

Any help doing this in `tidyr` or `reshape` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've seen several questions/answers that are very similar (one may be an exact duplicate) - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729506/combine-multiple-columns-into-tidy-data?lq=1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns-with-tidyr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be some efficient way, but this is one way.

Working separately for date and value,

```
#for date
df.date<-df%>%select(id, age,date1,date2, date3)%>%melt(id.var=c("id", "age"), value.name="date")
#for val
df.val<-df%>%select(id, age,value1,value2, value3)%>%melt(id.var=c("id", "age"), value.name="value")
```

Now join,

```
df2<-full_join(df.date, df.val, by=c("id", "age"))
df2%>%select(-variable.x, -variable.y)

 id age       date value
1   1  40 2015-07-19    28
2   1  40 2015-07-19    49
3   1  40 2015-07-19    24
4   2  33 2015-06-27    99
5   2  33 2015-06-27    18
6   2  33 2015-06-27    26
7   3  75 2015-07-07    63
8   3  75 2015-07-07    74
9   3  75 2015-07-07    72
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion gathering both types of columns separately using tidyr instead - I post the answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this trying to learn about using `gather` with a mix of dates and values.

The existing answers lose information about which instance the date-value pair came from, ie, instance 1 for date1 & value1, etc. This may not be important, but here's a tidyverse option that keeps the instance.

```
library(stringr) # not necessary but nice
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    gather(key, val, -id, -age) %>% 
    mutate(
        measure = str_sub(key,1,-2), 
        instance = str_sub(key, -1)
    ) %>% 
    select(-key) %>% 
    spread(measure, val) %>% 
    mutate(date = as.Date(date, origin="1970-01-01")) # restore date class
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question and data format for a dataset I was working on.  Crowdsourced the answer at work. A couple of us came up with a single `tidyr` and `dplyr` pipeline solution. Using the same simulated **df** from original question.

```
df %>%
    gather(key = date_position, value = date, starts_with("date")) %>%
    gather(key = value_position, value = value, starts_with("value")) %>%
    mutate(date_position = gsub('[^0-9]', "", date_position),
           value_position = gsub('[^0-9]', "", value_position)) %>%
    filter(date_position == value_position) %>%
    select(-ends_with("position")) %>%
    arrange(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The same strategy but using `tidyr` instead looks as follows:

```
df.value <- df %>%
    gather(key="foo", value="value", starts_with("value"))
df.date <- df %>%
    gather(key="bar", value="date", starts_with("date"))
```

After controlling the resulting dimensions (careful with `NA` values - there is also a `na.rm` argument to the `gather` function) I joined the data.frames using base/dplyr functions:

```
df.long <- data.frame(select(df.value, id, age, value), select(df.date, date))
```

I am certain there is a much more elgant way to both parts, but it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This does a `reshape` and then sorts the rows.

The first two lines just set up the `v.names` and `varying` arguments to `reshape`.  `v.names` defines the new column names and `varying`, is a list whose two components contain logical selection vectors of the `date` and `value` columns respectively.

The last line of code does the sorting and can be omitted if the row order does not matter.

No packages are used.

```
v.names <- c("date", "value")
varying <- lapply(v.names, startsWith, x = names(df))
r <- reshape(df, dir = "long", varying = varying, v.names = v.names)
r[order(r$id, r$time), ]
```

giving the following where the id and time columns relate the output rows back to the input:

```
     id age time       date value
1.1   1  12    1 2015-08-14     3
1.2   1  12    2 2015-07-11    24
1.3   1  12    3 2015-07-04     4
2.1   2  92    1 2015-08-03    17
2.2   2  92    2 2015-07-19    52
2.3   2  92    3 2015-07-01    93
3.1   3  28    1 2015-08-24    86
3.2   3  28    2 2015-08-12    80
3.3   3  28    3 2015-09-01    56
4.1   4  45    1 2015-09-13    78
4.2   4  45    2 2015-07-07    92
4.3   4  45    3 2015-08-10    81
5.1   5  25    1 2015-08-27    95
5.2   5  25    2 2015-09-08    68
5.3   5  25    3 2015-06-27    82
6.1   6   1    1 2015-08-21    16
6.2   6   1    2 2015-06-15    35
6.3   6   1    3 2015-07-24    30
7.1   7   7    1 2015-07-19    59
7.2   7   7    2 2015-07-08    33
7.3   7   7    3 2015-08-11    49
8.1   8  71    1 2015-07-28    19
8.2   8  71    2 2015-06-29    74
8.3   8  71    3 2015-08-05    25
9.1   9  59    1 2015-07-05    64
9.2   9  59    2 2015-09-04    30
9.3   9  59    3 2015-07-30    74
10.1 10  96    1 2015-09-12    69
10.2 10  96    2 2015-07-23    72
10.3 10  96    3 2015-08-19    23
```