# reshaping k columns to 2 columns representing sequential pairs of the values of the k variables

Tags: r, reshape, data-management

I have a data frame like this:

```
id y1 y2 y3 y4  
--+--+--+--+--
a |12|13|14|  
b |12|18|  |
c |13|  |  |
d |13|14|15|16
```

I want to reshape in such a way that I end with two columns. The above example would then become:

```
id from to  
--+----+--- 
a |12  |13  
a |13  |14  
a |14  |
b |12  |18
b |18  |  
c |13  |
d |13  |14  
d |14  |15  
d |15  |16
```

Each `id` has a 'from' and a 'to' per pair of year values.
Does anybody know of an easy way to do this? I tried using `reshape2`. I also looked at [Combine Multiple Columns Into Tidy Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729506/combine-multiple-columns-into-tidy-data) but I think my case is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to loop over the pairs of columns and `rbind` to union them:

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(2:(length(df)-1), 
               function(x) setNames(df[!is.na(df[,x]),c(1,x,x+1)], 
                                    c("id", "from", "to"))))
   id from to
1   a   12 13
2   b   12 18
3   c   13 NA
4   d   13 14
11  a   13 14
21  b   18 NA
41  d   14 15
12  a   14 NA
42  d   15 16
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution uses `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 y1 = c(12, 12, 13, 13),
                 y2 = c(13, 18, NA, 14),
                 y3 = c(14, NA, NA, 15),
                 y4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 16),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(STEP, from, -id) %>%
  drop_na(from) %>%
  arrange(id, STEP) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(to = lead(from)) %>%
  select(-STEP)
```

Comment: Neat, though producing an extra row

Comment: @HubertL Thanks for your comment. I know the last row is not in OP's desired output, but I feel it should be there. At least I don't find a good logic to exclude the last row because the last row of id `a`, `b`, and `c` are also there.

Comment: It shouldn't, as its `to` value is generated by `lead`. A rearrangement: `df %>% gather(var, from, -id) %>% 
    arrange(id, var) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(to = lead(from)) %>% 
    #slice(-n()) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(from), var != 'y4') %>% select(-var)`

Comment: If `id=="b"` has an `18-NA` row, I can't see how `id=="d"` shouldn't have a `16-NA` row.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for your suggestion. Let's wait for OP's clarification on this. Currently, I agree with @thelatemail. If `18-NA` is in id `b`, `16-NA` should also be in id `d`.

Answer (score 4):

In base R, `stack` and shift everything back one row in each group. Using @ycw's example data, `dt`:

```
tmp <- na.omit(cbind(dt[1], stack(dt[-1])[-2]))
names(tmp)[2] <- "from"
tmp$to <- with(tmp, ave(from, id, FUN=function(x) c(tail(x,-1),NA) ))
tmp[order(tmp$id),]

#   id from to
#1   a   12 13
#5   a   13 14
#9   a   14 NA
#2   b   12 18
#6   b   18 NA
#3   c   13 NA
#4   d   13 14
#8   d   14 15
#12  d   15 16
#16  d   16 NA
```

In the world of `data.table`, the same logic applies. `melt`, then `shift` `by=` id:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(dt)

melt(dt, id.vars="id", value.name="from")[
  !is.na(from),-"variable"][, to := shift(from,1,type="lead"), by=id
][order(id)]
```